# Expo update fails because it can't find "noop.js"?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, apple-developer

I'm trying to run my React Native application, developed with Expo, on an ios device I own. Following advice from [this](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/997) thread, I've set the "preview" profile in `eas.json` to contain the following rule:

```
"ios": {
  "simulator": true
}
```

And I attempted to use the following command to build the JS bundle locally and have it served from Expo's servers:

```
eas update --branch preview --message "test ios version"
```

However, I get an extremely bizarre error that I cannot for the life of me find anywhere on the internet. The output from the above command gives the error below.

```
Cannot find module 'expo/bin/cli.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\{my project}\noop.js
    Error: Cannot find module 'expo/bin/cli.js'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\{my project}\noop.js
    Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

I tried reinstalling the expo cli (`npm install -g expo-cli --force`) in case this was the issue but obviously that did not resolve the problem. The only online resource I could find mentioning "noop.js" is [this](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/2048) issue which seems unrelated.

What exactly is "noop.js"? It doesn't seem like other dependencies, otherwise why would it be in the root project folder? How can I create this file or otherwise get `eas update` to work?

I'm trying to run my React Native application, developed with Expo, on an ios device I own. Following advice from [this](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/997) thread, I've set the "preview" profile in `eas.json` to contain the following rule:

```
"ios": {
  "simulator": true
}
```

And I attempted to use the following command to build the JS bundle locally and have it served from Expo's servers:

```
eas update --branch preview --message "test ios version"
```

However, I get an extremely bizarre error that I cannot for the life of me find anywhere on the internet. The output from the above command gives the error below.

```
Cannot find module 'expo/bin/cli.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\{my project}\noop.js
    Error: Cannot find module 'expo/bin/cli.js'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\{my project}\noop.js
    Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
```

I tried reinstalling the expo cli (`npm install -g expo-cli --force`) in case this was the issue but obviously that did not resolve the problem. The only online resource I could find mentioning "noop.js" is [this](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/2048) issue which seems unrelated.

What exactly is "noop.js"? It doesn't seem like other dependencies, otherwise why would it be in the root project folder? How can I create this file or otherwise get `eas update` to work?

Comment: At this point I'd even be satisfied with any workaround that would allow me to get the application to run on my ios device, as long as I can do it without needing Xcode (I don't have a macOS device) or paying the exorbitant fees of an Apple Developer account. I'm not set on "eas update".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer was to reinstall the `eas-cli`, and to also update the rule within `eas.json` to use the newest version:

```
"cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.18.3"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this issue after I had to update the expo SDK for an old project.I was able to solve it by deleting my yarn.lock file (I assume it will work similarly with package-lock file for npm)

I then went into my package.json and saw that I had "expo-cli": "^6.3.10" installed there. I then deleted it. I reinstalled expo-cli globally with yarn using

yarn global add eas-cli

after that eas update "worked". I got a new error but at least it wasnt this one.

good luck

Comment: I tried uninstalling and updating expo-cli in the manner you described in case somehow the global install I mentioned in my question was conflicting with the local dev dependency and the error message remained the same. However because of your answer I realized I hadn't tried updating eas-cli and that turned out to be the problem, so thank you!